# Formular Derivation - Expected Value Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, truncated-normal-distribution

i want to derive the following expected value formular for $p(x)= N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution):

$$E[X|a<X<b]=\mu+\sigma\frac{\phi(\alpha)-\phi(\beta)}{\Phi(\alpha)-\Phi(\beta)}$$

with $\phi(y):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}, \Phi(y):=\frac{1+erf(y/\sqrt(2))}{2}$ and 
$\alpha:=\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}, \beta:=\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$ .

here's what i got so far:
$$E:=\int_a^b xp(x)dx=\int_a^b (x-\mu)p(x)dx+\int_a^b \mu p(x)dx$$

the last integral simplifies to: $$\int_a^b \mu p(x)dx=\mu(\bar\Phi(b)-\bar\Phi(a))$$ with $$\bar\Phi(y):=\frac{1+erf((x-\mu)/\sqrt{2\sigma^2})}{2}$$

for the middle integral i got: $$\int_a^b(x-\mu)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{(a-\mu)/\sigma}^{(b-\mu)/\sigma}ze^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz=\sigma(-\phi(\beta)+\phi(\alpha))$$

resulting in: $$E=\sigma(-\phi(\beta)+\phi(\alpha))+\mu(\bar\Phi(b)-\bar\Phi(a))$$.

not quite what i was looking for, somebody sees where i did a mistake?

Comment: Doing it for a standard normally distribution variable with unit variance makes it easier. It is easier to do it for only one-sided truncation. The other one will follow easily. A key step is stating that the derivative of $\phi(x)$ is equal to $-x\phi(x)$.

Comment: You forgot to divide everything by $\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)$: all your calculations are using the Normal density rather than the truncated Normal density.

Comment: why do i have to divide by $\Phi(\beta)-\Phi(\alpha)$ ?

Comment: Otherwise your density does not integrate to one.